# Bootstrap 2.1.0 and google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get google maps working on bootstrap 2.1.0.

- map doesn't get proper size
- it's not centered

any hint?

Please don't answer

```css
#map_canvas img { 
  max-width: none; 
}
```

because this is fixed in bootstrap 2.0.4

Comment: just take the example from google maps documentation and place it in a div of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I always give the map canvas absolute dimensions for the map to appear.
I use this code for example, to make the map fill the whole document display area:

```
var wnd = $(window);
var jMap = $("#map");
var map = new google.maps.Map(jMap[0],
{
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.50714570, 5.419846499999999),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

function resize()
{
    jMap.width(wnd.width());
    jMap.height(wnd.height());
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}

wnd.resize(resize);
resize(); // Initial resize
```

Where `map` is the id of the map div